# Is it normal that docker runs configuration from the beggining after PC reboot?

Tags: docker

**Im using docker toolbox**

Just like in the question. I can't just reboot PC and type docker in CMD because then nothing is going to happend, just like docker would never be installed. At first, I have to turn on the Docker Quickstart Terminal and wait for the whole automatic configuration to be done, only then I can use it.

Comment: After the PC is rebooted, it takes some time for Docker to start up again. It doesn't keep running during the reboot. You have to wait for it to start before you can use it; on my Windows 10 installation, it sends three separate notifications as it is being started.

Comment: But I can reboot PC, use it for even 10 hours straight and Docker still won't configure. I have to manually click the Docker Quickstart Terminal AND ONLY THEN docker runs automatic configuration which takes about 20-30 seconds. It is looking for ip etc. etc.